# yii 1.0 https in getbaseurl not working on aws load balancer

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, redirect, yii, https

I am trying to move my website to https for all urls. I am using aws server instances with load balancer. I have managed to redirect site to https while on http through .htaccess (as posted below) but wherever i have used `Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).` it returns urls with http but not https.

Could anyone please help me to sort this out. I want all URLs to be HTTPS.

I have tried to look into base classes and found that there is a function in `chttprequest` class to check if connection is secure or not but this function seems not working. Please help.

```
public function getIsSecureConnection()
{
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) 
           && (strcasecmp($_SERVER['HTTPS'],'on') === 0 || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) 
           || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) 
           && strcasecmp($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'],'https') === 0;
}
```

**.htaccess (This is working fine.)**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your `protected/config/main.php` file to change the default value. Add a request component, and configure `baseUrl` property.

```
'components' => array(
        ...
        'request' => array(
            'baseUrl' => 'https://www.example.com',
        ),
    ),
```

The `baseUrl` now will be `https` from now. You don't have to change anything in `chttprequest` request.

Comment: Big thanks for your help but now if set baseUrl in main.php as follows

https://example.com/

and then call it Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) in any view file, It will return a weird URL as follows:

https://example.com/http://example.com/index.php

I checked in **CHttpRequest** class function **getBaseUrl** it has following code in it

`$this->getHostInfo() . $this->_baseUrl : $this->_baseUrl;`

hostinfo is returning the first part and _baseUrl is returning the second part.

it is not working as expected.